# Преобразовать DICOM Image в JPG

Tags: c++, qtcreator, mingw, поиск-библиотек

С помощью чего можно преобразовать DICOM Image to JPG? 
Есть библиотеки помимо DCMTK?

Comment: Я как-то использовал для этих целей ImageJ. Он написан на java, из-за чего я тогда использовал Scala вместо C++, но для ImageJ вроде бы есть привязки для C++. Если не найдете ничего лучше, можно попытаться использовать их.  Основные лицензии - Public Domain и BSD-2.

Comment: Где можно посмотреть библиотеку ImageJ?

Comment: ImageJ - это набор библиотек(плагинов) и конечных инструментов в одном проекте. Я сам точно не уверен, где там что находится, свои исходники я потерял. Скачать можно на https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/download.html , может быть полезна https://imagej.net/DICOM . Я так и не нашел информации по C++ привязкам, судя по всему, придется писать модуль на java и подключать через Invocation API. В принципе, это не сложно - на входе массив байтов, на выходе массив байтов, главное разобраться с самим ImageJ. Но вариант, конечно, неудобный.

Comment: Нашел исходники, ImageJ есть в Maven, я подключал как `"net.imagej" % "ij"   % "1.51h"` (sbt), ну или можно посмотреть тут: https://imagej.net/Maven . Я открывал изображения через `ij.IJ.openImage(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath)` , но вроде бы была возможность читать из буфера, которая мне не понадобилась.